# Find items inside of the Object by Value and assign them to the inicial Searched value

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6, filter, match

Basically I´m trying to match values from JSON, they have parent-child relashionship

Array:

```
{
    "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03",
    "color_name": "",
  },
  {
    "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03-YEL-UNI",
    "color_name": "Amarillo",
  }
  {
    "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03-ROJ-UNI",
    "color_name": "Rojo",
  }
```

I need to get the item that is parent (based on the sku `.length` - there is a pattern in the data) and asign the children to the parent.

Looking for something like this:

```
{
    "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03",
    "children": "BAG-WM-03-YEL-UNI, BAG-WM-03-ROJ-UNI",
  }
```

P.S. Beginner here, please be gentle :)

Comment: What is considered as a "*pattern*"? Can the array have anything other than `BAG-WM-03-` prefix?

Comment: is the array sorted?

Comment: Please create a working example of what you are working with. I don't understand the relationship.

Comment: @adiga yes, there are, the items have specified the parent and child relashiopnship, but I want to get it working using the main value ('sku') in this case.

Comment: What is considered as `parent` item: Is it items with `item_sku.length === 9`? Or `item_sku` with only two `-` in them? Is it sorted according to the parent (Eg: once another parent `BAG-WM-04` comes up, there won't be anymore items with `BAG-WM-03`)

Comment: That is correct, `BAG-WM-03` is an unique value that won't appear anymore.

Comment: You haven't answered other questions as to what is a parent item. Will the entire array always have only one "parent" item? There won't be a `"item_sku": "BAG-WM-04"` in this array? Is the parent always the first element?

Comment: No, it's totally random. that is why the exact match of the sku has to be used. I will try later, but the Maheer answer should work.

Comment: There might be some easier ways to do this if you can clarify these things but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Create deep copy of given array and then use `map()` to change remove property `color_name` and add new property `children` and set it to `[]`
- Use `forEach()` to iterate over the copy of data.
- Use `find()` to get the object whose `item_sku` is in start of the current item's `item_sku`. This will be the parent.
- If you find the parent push the element to children of that parent.
- At the end `filter()` out those object whose `children` doesn't contain any element.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03",
    "color_name": "",
  },
  {
    "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03-YEL-UNI",
    "color_name": "Amarillo",
  },
  {
    "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03-ROJ-UNI",
    "color_name": "Rojo",
  }
]

let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)).map(x => ({item_sku:x.item_sku,children:[]}));

clone.forEach(a => {
  let parent = clone.find(x => a.item_sku.startsWith(x.item_sku) && a !== x);
  if(parent) parent.children.push(a.item_sku);
})

clone = clone.filter(x => x.children.length)
console.log(clone)
```

Answer (score 1):

The basics.

> ### Plant a tree!
>
> Assuming you have only the strings as keys and this strings contains their own relationship by containing beginning strings which are nodes themself.
>
> Then assume to get an ordered array of this string and take a look to the given values like
>
> ```
> a
> ab
> abc
> bb
> bba
> bbab
> ```
>
> Then iterate the sorted array and take this string and go backwards until you find a string which is the actual string starting with. Take it as parent and assign the actual string and its generated object as children.
>
> If no parent is found take an empty string as parent.
>
> As result return the children of the virtual parent with empty string as root nodes.

```js
function getTree(array) {
    var o = {};
    array.forEach((k, i, a) => {
        o[k] = o[k] || { id: k };
        while (i-- && !k.startsWith(a[i]));

        var parent = a[i] || '';
        o[parent] = o[parent] || { id: parent };
        o[parent].children = o[parent].children || [];
        o[parent].children.push(o[k]);
    });
    return o[''].children;
}


var data = ['a', 'bb', 'ab', 'abc', 'bba', 'bbab'],
    tree = getTree(data.sort());

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The implementation.

After getting a tree out of the data, you need to get the nodes with their relationship in a flat array.

```js
function getFlat(nodes, parent) {
    return nodes.reduce((r, { id, children = [] }) => {
        var temp = { id };
        if (parent) {
            parent.children = parent.children || [];
            parent.children.push(id);
        }
        r.push(temp, ...getFlat(children, temp));
        return r;
    }, []);
}

function getTree(array) {
    var o = {};
    array.forEach((k, i, a) => {
        o[k] = o[k] || { id: k };
        while (i-- && !k.startsWith(a[i]));

        var parent = a[i] || '';
        o[parent] = o[parent] || { id: parent };
        o[parent].children = o[parent].children || [];
        o[parent].children.push(o[k]);
    });
    return o[''].children;
}

var data = ['a', 'bb', 'ab', 'abc', 'bba', 'bbab'],
    nodes = getTree(data.sort()),
    flat = getFlat(nodes);

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let items = [
    {
        "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03",
        "color_name": ""
    },
    {
        "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03-YEL-UNI",
        "color_name": "Amarillo"
    },
    {
        "item_sku": "BAG-WM-03-ROJ-UNI",
        "color_name": "Rojo"
    }
]

items = items.map(item => ({
    ...item, 
    children: items
        .filter(newItem => 
            newItem.item_sku.indexOf(item.item_sku) == 0 
            && newItem.item_sku.length > item.item_sku.length
            )
        .map(newItem => newItem.item_sku)
})).map(item => ({
    item_sku: item.item_sku,
    children: item.children
})).filter(item => item.children.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the `sku.length` may be different each time. Sorry for not mentioning this previously.

Comment: sku.length will not effect the solution until and unless it is not undefined. I took that array as sample only. :)